# how to count days elpased between each interval using mySQL?

Tags: mysql, date, apache-superset

I have a table that has date range and i want to calculate the days that has been elapsed between 2 date

| workorder | sequence | start date | end date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 2024-01-02 | 2024-01-05 |
| 123 | 2 | 2024-02-01 | 2024-02-06 |
| 123 | 3 | 2024-02-10 | 2024-02-11 |
| 200 | 1 | 2024-03-01 | 2024-03-02 |
| 200 | 2 | 2024-03-15 | 2024-03-16 |

Basically, i want to know the date elapsed from the end date of 123 | 1 to the start date of 123 | 2

Im expecting to get output such as below

| workorder | sequence | start date | end date | elapsed day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 2024-01-02 | 2024-01-05 | 0 |
| 123 | 2 | 2024-02-01 | 2024-02-06 | 27 |
| 123 | 3 | 2024-02-10 | 2024-02-11 | 4 |
| 200 | 1 | 2024-03-01 | 2024-03-02 | 0 |
| 200 | 2 | 2024-03-15 | 2024-03-16 | 13 |

The criteria is based on the workorder number and sequence

Example Calc:

1. End Date of 123|1 - Start Date of 123|2 = 27
2. End Date of 123|2 - Start Date of 123|3 = 4
3. End Date of 200|1 - Start Date of 200|2 = 13

The example of 2 workorder number which are 123 and 200 but the elapsed calculation based on the same work order number and according to its ***own sequence***.

Im lost

Comment: DATEDIFF(start_date, LAG(end_date))